# How to easily get network path to the file you are working on?

Tags: excel, filepath, excel-2010

In Excel 2003 there used to be a command that I added to my toolbar that was called Address (if I remember correctly) and it would show the fully-qualified network path to the file I had open.  For example: `\\ads\IT-DEPT-DFS\data\Users\someguy\somefile.xls`

This made it easy to grab this string and pop it in an email when you wanted to share the file with a coworker.  I don't see this option in Excel 2010 but find myself needing to send/receive Excel files a lot now.  Coworkers will give vague references to "it is on the share drive" or email the file as an attachment (ugh!).

Anyone know if something comparable exists in Excel 2010?

UPDATE: I found this mapping of Excel 2003 to 2007 commands.  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/redir/AM010186429.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010086048

Web>Address is what I was using - looks like that became "Document Location" in 2007.  But they removed/obfuscated this again in 2010.  I am trying to find a mapping like this for 2007 to 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my own question.  The only way I have found that works consistently and instantaneously is to:

1) Create a link in my "Favorites" to the directory I use

2) Update the properties on that favorite to be an absolute path (\\ads\IT-DEPT-DFS\Data\MAILROOM)

3) When saving a new file, I navigate to that directory only via the Favorites directory created above (or you can use any Shortcut with an absolute path)

4) After saving, go to the File tab and the full path can be copied from the top of the Info (default) section

Answer (score 10):

Right click on the ribbon and choose `Customize the ribbon`.  From the `Choose commands from:` drop down, select `Commands not in the ribbon`.

That is where I found the `Document location` command.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to get the filepath of the file in Excel 2010.

1) Right click on the Ribbon.
2) Click on "Customize the Ribbon"
3) On the right hand side, click "New Group." This will add a new tab to the Ribbon. 
         If you want to, click on the "Rename" button the right side and name your tab. For example, I named the tab "Doc Path." This step is optional
4) Under "Choose Commands From" on the left hand side, choose "Commands Not in the Ribbon."
5) Select "Document Location" and "Add" it to your newly created group.
6) The filepath should now appear under the newly created tab on the ribbon.

Comment: First, thanks.  The trouble I have with this is that the file location does not update when you save the file - it just stays as "Book 1" until you close and open it.

Comment: This is very useful for existing files though so I am using it in addition to my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In Win7 (and Vista I think), you can `Shift+Right Click` the file in question and select `Copy as path` to get the full network path. Note: if the shared drive is mapped to a letter, you will get that path instead (ie: `X:\someguy\somefile.xls`)

Comment: The biggest problem with that is the shared drive letter - not always consistent between users. You also need to locate the file.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a slightly old question, but it was driving me crazy too - and today I've found the solution that I believe the questioner was looking for (i.e. a direct mapping of Excel 2003's Web-->Address to the Excel 2010 Ribbon).

To customise the Ribbon, right-click on it and choose 'Customise the Ribbon'. You can make a new tab/group, or add this to an existing one. Choose to look in "All commands" and then the one you are after is simply called "Address". This puts a box with the full network path in it (that can be selected to copy) into the ribbon, just like Excel 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Just paste the below formula in any of the cells, it will render the path of the file:

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("]",CELL("filename"),1))
```

The above formula works in any version of Excel.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to display the `Document Location module` in Office 2010.

`File -> Options -> Quick Access Toolbar`

From the 
`Choose commands` list 
select `All Commands`
find `"Document Location"` press the `"Add>>"` button.

press `OK`.

Viola, the file path is at the top of your 2010 office document.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to find address path in Excel 2010:

File - info - properties (on right) - (drop-down menu) - advanced properties - general tab

You will get to the same properties box that was so simple to find in Excel 2003.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this formula to get the path of the file:

```
=LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("[",CELL("filename"),1)-1)
```