# How to find the full network path of an excel file shared in a network?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have a macro-enabled worksheet that resides in a shared location on my PC. This sheet, used to collect some data from employees resides in a shared location in network. It has a feature where users are sent reminder mails when they fail to fill data in time.  In the mail content I like to add the local network path to my excel file.

I accomplish this by adding the code

```
“You can access the tool from the location " & ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

On sending mails using this code I get the path to this folder as C:\Users\XYZ\Hello.xlsm
I would like to send the network path with IP address so that users can directly copy the path into run and access the file.

Interesting thing is that if I send the mail from another system other than mine by accessing the file form my shared folder, the mail is sent with the network path. Can anyone help on this?

I use Excel 2007

Comment: Please see this thread. Is it a something similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261085/excel-2010-how-to-easily-get-network-path-to-the-file-you-are-working-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved my problem. I used a function to find the computer name and manipulated `ThisWorkbook.Fullname`

```
Private Declare Function GetComputerName Lib "kernel32" _
    Alias "GetComputerNameA" _
    (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

Function ReturnComputerName() As String
    Dim rString As String * 255, sLen As Long, tString As String
    tString = ""
    On Error Resume Next
    sLen = GetComputerName(rString, 255)
    sLen = InStr(1, rString, Chr(0))
    If sLen > 0 Then
        tString = Left(rString, sLen - 1)
    Else
        tString = rString
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    ReturnComputerName = UCase(Trim(tString))
End Function    


Sub GetThePath()
    If Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, 2) <> "\\" Then
        If Sheet4.Range("B15").Value = "No" Then
            CN = "file:\\" & Evaluate("=ReturnComputerName()") & "\"
        End If
        mynames = ThisWorkbook.Path
        mynamesa = Split(mynames, "\")
        elem = UBound(mynamesa)
        mynames = mynamesa(elem)
        mynames = mynames & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
        mynames = CN & mynames
    ElseIf Left(ThisWorkbook.FullName, 2) = "\\" Then
        mynames = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    End If
End Sub
```

Demerit: Cannot find the correct path if the file is in a folder within a shared folder.

Answer (score 1):

Why the ip address? Couldn't you use the computer name.

```
file:\\computername\Users\XYZ\Hello.xlsm.
```

But to be perfectly honest, I think you are setting yourself up for a some pain doing things this way. Why not an HTML form and a bit of PHP putting the data into MySQL which you can then extract into Excel or anything else?

--Edit

Here is a link to a possible method of getting the computername. I haven't tried it so I can't say if it works or not.

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/retrieving_the_computer_name_or_logged_in_user_name/

Comment: Nice suggestion to do it with PHP but I would like to do this with excel itself. I am not so aware of PHP also. How can I retrive computername using excel?

Comment: The code does return the computer name. I need a link that users can copy into run to access the file. How to manipulate this?

Answer (score 1):

Your base is probably fixed, so i would go for a simple solution like:

```
Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName,"C:\Users\","file:\\computername\Users\)
```

Comment: This can be used but in may case C:\Users\ won't always be constant. The file may be within a folder with in a shared location.

Comment: In that case ThisWorkbook.FullName will terurn the network path, and the replace has no effect, so you should be good...